# How to align a Latex table that uses \multicolumn?

Tags: formatting, filetype-tex, alignment

I want to align a Latex table the way it appears in the final document.

[image]

There are various Vim plugins for aligning tables ([2](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294), [3](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), [4](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)), but none of them handle the spanning cell correctly. The code should be aligned like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{spanning cell} & cell3 \\
    cell1 & cell2                       & cell3 \\
\end{tabular}
```

but ends up looking like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{spanning cell} & cell3 \\
    cell1                               & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the original text? You have given only those expected and not expected results.

Comment: Why? I don't think the actual text has any impact here?

Comment: I will try to align the original code and check with the expected one. Only then I with be able to answer